# Understanding scala function defitions that return functions

Tags: scala, function, lambda

I need some help  understanding what this notation means such that going forward I don't get confused.

```
private[netty4] val cookieToNetty: Cookie => NettyCookie = c => {
```

The code snippet below shows its usage:

```
  def encodeServer(cookie: Cookie): String = {
    val encoded = serverEncoder.encode(cookieToNetty(cookie))
    if (CookieMap.includeSameSite) SameSiteCodec.encodeSameSite(cookie, encoded)
    else encoded
  }



      private[netty4] val cookieToNetty: Cookie => NettyCookie = c => {
    val nc = new NettyDefaultCookie(c.name, c.value)
    nc.setDomain(c.domain)
    nc.setPath(c.path)
    // We convert the Durations to Ints to circumvent maxAge being
    // Int.MinValue.seconds, which does not equal Duration.Bottom, even though
    // they have the same integer value in seconds.
    if (c.maxAge.inSeconds != Cookie.DefaultMaxAge.inSeconds) {
      nc.setMaxAge(c.maxAge.inSeconds)
    }
    nc.setSecure(c.secure)
    nc.setHttpOnly(c.httpOnly)
    if (shouldWrap(c)) nc.setWrap(true)
    nc
  }
```

So to me I tried to break it down like this:

```
private[netty4] val cookieToNetty: Cookie => NettyCookie = c => { 
...
}
```

cookieNetty is a function, and it takes a type `Cookie` as a parameter.   And this then returns another function that takes a `NettyCookie` and `c` as a parameter??
**I need an explanation to understand these types of function definitions, are these called inline lambda expressions?**

My second confusion is, since `encodeServer` returns a string, the val encoded must also be a string, yet the function `cookieToNetty` is returning a `nc` which is not a string.

How does this work?  Maybe there is an implicit?

Source: https://github.com/twitter/finagle/blob/develop/finagle-base-http/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finagle/http/netty4/Netty4CookieCodec.scala#L63

Comment: `c` is the parameter of type `Cookie` here. `cookieToNetty` is just a function that takes a `c` of type `Cookie` and returns a `NettyCookie`. Can't comment on the second half of the questions without knowing what `serverEncoder.encode` does

Comment: See also: [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)

Comment: `serverEncoder.encode()` takes a `NettyCookie` (as returned by `cookieToNetty()`) and returns a `String` that is stored in `encoded`.

Comment: *"`cookieNetty` is a function, and it takes a type `Cookie` as a parameter. And this then returns another function that takes a `NettyCookie` and `c` as a parameter??"* Syntax `val cookieToNetty: Cookie => NettyCookie = c => {...}` means `val cookieToNetty: (Cookie => NettyCookie) = (c => {...})`. `cookieToNetty` is a function `c => {...}` (mapping `c` into `{...}`). `Cookie => NettyCookie` is the type of this function.